# why query to find the 2nd highest salary of the employee is not working in mysql 5.1?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find the salary of the second-highest paid employee.

My expected output is 9000 but it prints 14000. I am unable to find my mistake. Kindly help me

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why are you not using the LIMIT command instead of your nested SQL query?

Comment: @ClaasWilke Mysql 5.1 automatically takes the limit value so i didn't used it

Comment: What about 
    SELECT salary FROM employee ORDER BY salary DESC LIMIT 1, 1
?

Comment: What if the two richest employees are both paid the same?

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
select max(salary) from table_name
where salary< (select max(salary) from table_name)
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8df37/1)

Comment: @ G one,my question is why its not working in mysql 5.1,how to find the 2 max of the employee in mysql 5.1

Comment: I ve changed the mysql version.. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!8/8df37/1 and its working even in mysql 5.1

Comment: @Gone i agree your answer,but why the query is not working in my RDBMS

Comment: @Krish : may be removing the screen shot and showing us the actual query and table schema will help....people here are lazy to type so much at one go!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use this query also ,

```
SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees WHERE salary < (SELECT MAX(salary) FROM employees)
```

Simply use sub query to get max salary from the employees table and check against same to get second highest.

Comment: I can see how you could use this to get the third highest salary also.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from table order by salary desc limit 2,1
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `limit 2,1` ?